# Prevent Meteor calls from being looped in the console

Tags: security, meteor, methods, console

I'm aware of the fact that you can't really prevent users from calling meteor methods from the console (correct me if I'm wrong).

I have a simple heads or tails game for users that track the stats of their games and the two methods I've created for both of them are `guessheads` and `guessTails`.  Based off of each result I just update the stats in those commands so the users don't have direct methods to updating their stats.

The stats are stored in the user's profile and cannot be edited by the user because of the following code:

```
Meteor.users.deny({
  update() { return true; }
});
```

My problem is that users are still able to call the `guessHeads` and `guessTails` commands from the console which isn't really an issue if copy pasting it is the same amount of effort as simply clicking the heads or tails button on in the ui.

But what if they run those commands in a large loop?  How can I prevent them from doing that, because it is currently possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
var throttledUsers = { }; // Outside of your methods but on the server.  I would probably use the module pattern for this.

guessHeads() {
    var currentUser = this.userId;
    if(!throttledUsers[currentUser]) {
        throttledUsers[currentUser] = true;
        //Do your logic.
        Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
            delete throttledUsers[currentUser];
        }, 1000); // Set the throttle timeout to whatever you want.
    } else {
        // Throw an exception or whatever you want.
    }
}
```

Basically what you're doing here is creating an object server-side that holds your users who have either called guessHeads or guessTails within the last second.  The timeout then removes those users from the object, and allows them to execute the guessHeads and guessTails logic again.

Comment: Could you explain more about what this actually does?

Comment: Ok, so in that case, for the on button click I should also do a Meteor.setTimeout so that this doesn't break for users who do manually click the button quicker than a second (or whatever other time)?

Comment: Yeah, you should probably do that as well so they know, or you can make the button disabled for that time period.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this solution when I test it tomorrow.

Comment: It's not working :/  No matter what, the user is always throttled with this code...

Answer (score 2):

Meteor's `ddp-rate-limiter` core package is designed to address this behavior.

Just add the package and then [follow the documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ddp-rate-limiter) to add a rule with `DDPRateLimiter.addRule()` of `type: 'method'` targeting the `guessHeads` and `guessTails` methods. You can limit the frequency of calls to these methods to whatever suits your application needs.

Comment: I actually just ran across this in reading the meteor guide.  You should use this instead.

Comment: Is this code supposed to be implemented on the client?